# how to show different markerInfoWindow?

Tags: ios, google-maps-markers, gmsmapview

i'm using GMS for ios. and i'm facing problem that i can't detect which marker did tapped!(Custom markerInfoWindow)

you can see my code for custom markerInfoWindow :

here i'm creating the markers :

```
 -(void)CreateMarks{
for (int l=0 ; l<self.NSMuatableArray.count; l++) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D pos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[self.NSMuatableArray objectAtIndex:l] objectForKey:@"lati"] doubleValue],[[[self.NSMuatableArray objectAtIndex:l] objectForKey:@"longi"] doubleValue]);
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
    marker.position=pos;
    marker.draggable = NO;
    marker.map = mapView_;
}}
```

here is the delegate :

```
-(UIView*)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker{

CustomInfoWindow*infoW = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InfoWindow" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

for (l=0; l<self.NSMuatableArray.count; l++) {

    infoW.Title.text =[[self.NSMuatableArray objectAtIndex:l ]objectForKey:@"Title"] ;
    infoW.Time.text = [[self.NSMuatableArray objectAtIndex:l ]objectForKey:@"Time"] ;

}



return infoW;
}
```

so how can detect which object just tapped ?

thanks.

Comment: How are you creating your markers? My guess is that the problem is starting there. And this loop doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, your `CreateMarks` method is correct, the only thing missing, is some way to identify the marker afterwards. Add this to it:

```
marker.userData = [self.NSMuatableArray objectAtIndex:l];
```

Now, on your `mapView:markerInfoWindow:`. This loop doesn't make sense. Instead, do something like this:

```
-(UIView*)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker{

    CustomInfoWindow*infoW = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InfoWindow" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDictionary * data = (NSDictionary*)marker.userData;

    infoW.Title.text =[data objectForKey:@"Title"];
    infoW.Time.text = [data objectForKey:@"Time"];

    return infoW;
}
```

The problem is that you probably didn't understand how this method really work. It is called every time the user taps on a marker. It is actually asking `What view should I show when this marker is tapped`. And you were simply running over all your markers and overwriting their data on the same view.

Now, `GMSMarker`'s have this cool property `userData` that can store whatever you like. It is useful to identify the marker later.

Comment: You're welcome. ;) but don't just paste it and accept it. Take some time to understand this concept of `dataSource`. It is broadly used in iOS.

Comment: _i made some changes in creating method_ .

how to remove all the markers ?i set `self.NSMuatableArray` to equal nil in UIBAction then it calls the creating method again with nil array which should detect first if `self.NSMuatableArray` is nil make `marker.map = nil`

Comment: @Gonzo Thanks you are saving my time  its working fine